# "Locked out" of account because Google OAuth account cannot be changed

Tags: feature-request, oauth2

TL;DR: It'd be fantastic if we had an option to "change account" with OAuth sign in.

I went to log into Stack Overflow in a new browser and picked one of my Google accounts to sign in with. Wrong account. It prompts me to create a new Stack Overflow account. There is now no way to say "use a different account" or even start over.

I deleted Stack Overflow cookies and it continues to prompt with the same account. The only way to use a different account is to sign out with the Google ID, which is a pain, because now I have to sign back in with all my Google IDs across all my usages.

Comment: I followed your steps to reproduce but was able to fix it from the account creation page by clicking on the Log In button at the top of the page. That took me back to the page to choose which account and clicking the Google button gave me the option to choose. If that didn't work for you there may also be a bug.

Comment: @BSMP each time I click Log In it returns to the Create New Account forms, so I was not able to choose. I was only signed in to one Google Account at the time.